# Notice: Undefined index: tipo_usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestLap\TC3\index.php on line 43

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo que al momento de que el usuario se loguee al sistema, aparezca en la página de main su nombre y el rango o jerarquía al cual pertenece. Había preguntado por un error aparente de sintaxis, pero después de corregir la misma, a la hora de ejecutar el código me sale este mensaje:

```
  Notice: Undefined index: tipo_usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestLap\TC3\index.php on line 43
```

Este es el código sobre el que estoy trabajando:

```
session_start();

if ($_POST) {

    $usuario = $_POST ['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cargo1 = $_POST['tipo_usuario'];

    $sql = "SELECT db_usuarios.id_usuario, db_usuarios.password, db_usuarios.usuario, db_usuarios.nombre_firma, db_roles.tipo_usuario FROM db_usuarios INNER JOIN db_roles ON db_usuarios.id_usuario = db_roles.id_rol WHERE db_usuarios.usuario='$usuario' AND db_roles.tipo_usuario='$cargo1'";
    //echo $sql;
    $resultado = $TC2P->query($sql);
    $num = $resultado->num_rows;

    if($num>0){
        $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
        $password_bd = $row['password'];

        $pass_c = sha1($password);

        if($password_bd == $pass_c) {

            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['usuario'];
            $_SESSION['nombre_firma'] = $row['nombre_firma'];
            $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['tipo_usuario'];


            header("Location: main.php");

        } else {
            echo "<div class='error12'>Error al escribir usuario o contraseña.</div>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "<div class='error12'>Error al escribir usuario o contraseña.</div>";
    }
}
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme con este problema, se lo voy a agradecer mucho. Soy muy nuevo en esto del MySQL y PHP y me encuentro aprendiendo un poco de todos estos lenguajes de programación.

Un gran saludo a todos y buen día.

Comment: En la consulta al final después del AND a tipo_usuario no le estas indicando de que tabla lo obtienes.

Comment: Esta manera de ejecutar la sentencia SQL es susceptible de inyección Msql, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php por otra parte, si ejecutas la consulta en tu gestor de BBDD, que valor obtienes para tipo_usuario?

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($row);` ?

Comment: Según el var_dump, para $row no me muestra absolutamente nada. ¿Será que es ese el problema?